# For Geb's given when then, is there a way to ignore an assertion in 'then'

Tags: assert, geb

**Situation**

For my test, I have a step that asserts the return value of a method. The method takes a boolean value as a parameter (among other things). I could create a new column with that boolean value, however _variableB happens to mirror the boolean value I want.

**Problem**

When I run this step, Geb asserts on `_variableB == 'some text'` itself, rather than just using it as a parameter.

```
then:
    MethodA(something, something, _variableB == 'some text')

where:
    _variableA | _variableB
```

**Question**

Is there a way of ignoring/disabling this assertion?

*Edit: inserted received error*

**Received error**

```
Condition not satisfied:

Validator.waitForxxxxxxOnValidate(_xxxxxxType, xxxxxData.xxxxxxIdHex, _receivers == 'partner2')
|                     |                            |                |            |             |          |
|                     null                         xxxxxx-xxx      |            |             partner1       false
class xx.xxxx.partner2.helpers.xxxxxxValidator                    |            |                        1 difference (75% similarity)
                                                                    |            |                        partner(1)
                                                                    |            |                        partner(2)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the error you are getting which makes you believe that `_variableB == 'some text'` is automatically asserted? Because based on the code snippet you provided I'm fairly certain that this is not the case.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Geb does not assert anything because it's not a testing framework, it's a browser automation framework. You seem to be using Spock, which is a testing framework and which performs implicit assertions based on `given/when/then` code labels.

Secondly, your assumption that `_receivers == 'partner2'` is asserted is incorrect. All that happens is that when the implicit assertion on the call to `Validator.waitForxxxxxxOnValidate()` fails (because it returns `null` as per the failure you included) Spock is printing partial values of the asserted expression to make it easier for you to understand why the assertion failed. It just shows you that the value of `_receivers` is `"partner1"` and that because it's not equal to `"partner2"` `false` is passed as the last argument of the call to `Validator.waitForxxxxxxOnValidate()`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I tend to get Geb and Spock mixed up, because I've only ever used them together.
But your explanation will definitely help me with a better understanding of both.